# URL in CSS no longer works in Vaadin 14.6

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin14

After upgrading from Vaadin 14.5 to 14.6 I'm facing problems with CSS that contains URL's that point to content.

For example, the following CSS no longer works:

```
:host([part="my-part"]) [part="reveal-button"]::before {
    content: url("../images/my-image.svg");
}
```

It fails to "compile" when running the build-frontend goal of the Vaadin Maven plugin with the following error:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/@vaadin/flow-frontend/styles/components/my-component.css
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '../images/my-image.svg' in '<Project Path>\node_modules\@vaadin\flow-frontend\styles\components'
```

The same error appears in the browser if I try to run the project. This CSS has worked fine in all previous versions of Vaadin 14.

Has anyone encountered anything similar, or have any ideas as to what has changed that might cause this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the new custom theme feature the .css loader has changed from `raw-loader` to `css-loader` but it shouldn't touch urls outside of `frontend/themes/[theme-name]` or `node_modules`

Is the  `styles/components/my-component.css` located in `src/main/resources/META-INF/frontend`, `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend` or `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` to be packaged as an add-on jar or compatibility mode?

As in that case the css would end up inside node_modules which might make a difference to the resolving.

As a workaround if you are not building an add-on you should be able to move the css and image to `{project_root}/frontend` and it should build fine.

Until release of 14.6.2 you can add the raw-loader dependency to a java class with
`@NpmPackage(value = "raw-loader", version = "3.1.0")`
and then add to `webpack.config.js` the lines

```
if(flowDefaults.module.rules[2].test.toString().includes('.css')) {
  flowDefaults.module.rules[2].use = [ {loader: 'raw-loader' }];
} else if(flowDefaults.module.rules[1].test.toString().includes('.css')) {
  flowDefaults.module.rules[1].use = [ {loader: 'raw-loader' }];
}
```

Comment: The CSS file is in:
<project_root>/<vaadin_module_dir>/frontend/styles/components/
The module is built to a JAR, which is eventually packaged in a WAR file to create the final product.

The image we're referencing is in a different module:
<project_root>/<resource_module_dir>/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/images
which is also included in the final WAR file.

Comment: You can then follow the issue https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/11015 I'll edit the response with an add-on workaround.

Comment: Thanks - the workaround doesn't seem to work very well for me. Each time I redeploy the application the Web Pack configuration is regenerated, so it gets quite cumbersome.

I'll simply hold off using 14.6 until the issue is fixed.

Comment: Sorry my bad. the workaround should be in webpack.config.js not .generated.

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck, I'm afraid. I get exactly the same error with the work-around in place in webpack.config.js

Comment: Would it be possible to have a minimal sample project?

Comment: I'll see what I can whip up. Might not have time to do it today. Should I attach it to the GitHub issue if I do? You can't attach stuff here, can you?

Comment: Yes if you get anything then adding it to the ticket would help tremendously on figuring out the issue.

Comment: I attached a small project that seems to fail in the same way our main project do to the GitHub issue - see https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/11015#issuecomment-844776143

Comment: Thanks. Tested the fix against that also and it should work as before after that.

Comment: Updated the workaround as the issue was not what I thought at the beginning.

Comment: I updated to Vaadin 14.6.2 when it was released - and now it's working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the css structure to follow the [new theme structure](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/using-themes) introduced in 14.6? It is not needed, but it is important context. I think it is at least related to your issue.

The path seems a little weird in your error messages, ending up in a node_modules folder. Could you share where this file is in, and what loads the file to your project?

With the new theme structure, I've used the following css to import images in css:

```css
  background: url('./images/fire.png');
```

And that was placed in a file: `frontend/themes/mythemename/mythemefile.css`

Comment: For the new theme it should be `styles.css` instead of `mythemefile.css`

Comment: I use styles.css purely as a file that imports all the other parts of the theme, so for me there, is nothing else that `includes`. But yes, you can place the content directly in `styles.css` as well.

Comment: That's a good way to use it for structure, just noted that if you don't use `styles.css` with an import you would not get the `mythemefile.css` into the theme build.

Comment: See comment on @MikaelGrankvist answer for file location. 

I have made no changes to accommodate for the new theme system - I thought (maybe naively ;-) ) that it wouldn't matter as long as we didn't use the new folder structure.

The CSS is imported using a statement like this from Java:
@CssImport(value = "./styles/components/my-component.css", themeFor = "my-component")