# How to copy the JPG or PNG files to node_modules in the production mode

Tags: vaadin

There is some png or jpg images which I used in CSS file. when I try to deploy them into product environment, I run "mvn clean -Pproduction" just as what I was told in Vaadin offical documentation.

But the build fails and It is saying that "Can not resolve "../img/active_point.png" in some css file.

By the way, I put my css file in the folder like:

"META-INF.resources.frontend.com.xx.xxframework.vaadin.styles"

While the image path is like:
"META-INF.resources.frontend.com.xx.xxframework.vaadin.img"

After I checked the offical documentation, it seems I had to add "includes"in the goal parameter.
So I modifyed the POM.xml file as following:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <includes>**/*.js,**/*.css,**/*.png,**/*.jpg</includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Just as you see, I add configuration, in which I add the includes.
But after I run ,there was still nothing in node_moduels@vaadin\flow-frontend\com\xx\xxframework\vaadin

Does anyone have any idea about this?

The vaadin version is 14.6.0

Comment: `..img/active_point.png` doesn't seem to be a valid path, did you mean to write `../img/active_point.png`?

Comment: Yes , it is ../img/active_point.png. It is a typo. I already correct the description.

Comment: It sounds like you may have run into the same issue as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580595/url-in-css-no-longer-works-in-vaadin-14-6/67580678

Comment: Yes， it seems the same issue. I upgrade vaadin version from 14.4.7 to 14.6.0. it doesn't come up with any error during the build process in 14.4.7 . but after I upgrade to 14.6.0, the errors appear.